# std::vector::reserve( unknown m ), I know that m<<N (usually) and know N

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, data-structures

I have codes that work on `N` objects, then return only result of **some** `m` indices, based of some custom condition.

**Here is a solid example** (query all `' '` characters on a string `str`):-

```
 std::vector<int> reports; //will keep index of ' ' in "str"
 for(int i=0;i<N;i++){  // str.size() = "N"
     bool condition = str.at(i)==' ';  //"str" is string   #B
     if(condition){ //rarely true
         reports.push_back(i); 
     }
 }
 //now reports.size() = m
```

In those blocks, I know that `m` always less than or equal `N`, and **usually** `m << N`.

In real life, the blocks are more complex, but share a similar algorithm :-

```
 //int "N" is a local variable, it is not a constant. 
 std::vector<Input> inputs; 
 std::vector<Report> reports;  //"Report" is any type of result, actually
 int outOfLoopVariable=0; 
 for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
     bool condition = some logic #B about "inputs[i]" and "outOfLoopVariable";
     outOfLoopVariable= ....; //some complex logic #B
     int var1 = ....; //some complex logic #B
     //var2, var3, etc.
     if(condition){ //rarely true
         reports.push_back(Report(i,var1,var2,...)); 
     }
 }
```

### Original Problem

The algorithm `#B` has total complexity = `O(N)`,
but the `std::vector::push_back`'s total complexity =

- `O(m*log(m))` in most case (when `m<<N`)
- `O(N*log(N))` in worst case (when `m~N`)

*As noted by **oLen**, it is totally wrong.
However, I decided to keep it for reference.*

### Problem

(**Edit**) The algorithm `#B` require to reallocation of `vector` many times.

### Question

<s>How to make the complexity of the above blocks to be O(N)?</s>
(**Edit**, thank **oLen**) How to avoid unnecessary internal reservation of `vector` (1->2->4->...)?

### My poor solutions

For many year, I have always worked around this problem by one of these approaches :-

1. `reports.reserve(N)` at first statement - It is an over-reservation in most case.
   It is really bad when `report` is a big object and `N` is very big (profiled, 10000+).
2. Do the loop 2 times.

   - The **first loop** determine `m`.
   - Then `reserve(m)`.
   - Finally, the **second loop** does the actual `reports.push_back(i);`
   - It is not convenient.  Code duplication tends to cause minor maintainability issue.
     (can be partially solved by `lambda[&]`, sacrifice readability a bit)
   - Furthermore, roughly speaking, complexity of `#B` is now `O(2*n)`
   - ... or `O(1.x*n)` if I can omit some computation of the **first loop**.

I hope there will be a better approach.

Comment: AFAIK  `std::vector` member function `puch_back` has `amortize O(1)`. I am not sure, how it become `(nlog(n))` in your case.

Comment: 1. You don't need to "do the loop 2 times". You can use `std::count` for the first one. 2. O(2*n) is O(N). 3. Is "string" `std::string`? If so, what is `str.get()`?

Comment: @juanchopanza  1. I will look at it.  It has lambda smell.  2. In practice, it is very different.  3. It is "get-char-at-index". Ok, I will edit it to "at".

Comment: @javaLover 1. Why is lambda "smell"? Anyway, `std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ');`. Maybe spend some time looking into the standard library. 2. O(N) is the same O(2*N), that is how complexity works. It doesn't matter if a *2 factor applies in practice, that isn't complexity.

Comment: @juanchopanza 1. I am looking at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).   It is about passing a function pointer/lambda as parameter, right?  I didn't mean it is bad, but I already mentioned about it in question.   My first example is just a (trivial) block to depict the problem.  I think it would be suitable than some cool snippet. (no?)   2.Yes, I understand its strict definition, but I think stating "O(2*N)" will be understandable than "about twice of the computation cost of the first case."  (no?)

Comment: @javaLover 1. No idea what you're trying to say. 2. Your O(NlogN) algo could have less computation cost than an O(1) algo in practice. That is why you need to profile a realistic scenario.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, sir.  Thank for your help.  I really should profile. :)

Comment: @javaLover I see you changed your question, which makes my answer below a bit out-of-topic... Anyway, I would avoid premature optimization and I don't think I could come up with a faster solution than with `push_back`. You might be interested in `std::vector::shrink_to_fit` though.

Comment: @oLen Sorry.  I reconsider, I should keep original question, and add the new one instead.   By the way, your old solution tick something in my head ... I think I can find a way to solve it now, that is why I accept it.  Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Just do not change your code, and do not use `reserve`.

`std::vector::push_back`'s complexity is constant (considering [amortized time](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/)) so you will be fine by just using it.

Comment: @javaLover Why would this mean O(n log n)? There is a clever algorithm how this happens so that when you consider what happened as a whole after adding all the elements, for one single addition this will be constant time. See http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9380/why-is-push-back-in-c-vectors-constant-amortized for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 3rd approach: use a linked list `report`. No over-reservation. No extra loop.

But can be slower.

Comment: Good trick  +1, but I will not use it.  It is actually slower than arrayList (std::vector), might be caused by memory defragmentation.

Comment: It almost certainly *will* be slower due to cache misses. A `std::list` should not be used for "performance", not even for operations where the big-O notation would suggest more speed; it should be used when you need its iterator-validity guarantees (e.g. when an element is removed, iterators to other elements remain valid).